# Is there a way to edit which navigation links are seen based on permissions in 2013?

Tags: permissions, navigation, view, hyperlink

I've been working this problem for a couple of days now and I've come to the conclusion that it's either something very simple that I am missing or it's something incredibly complex that I can't figure out.

I have the site divided into two portions. An end user side and an admin side. The admin side needs to see the links at the top that will take them back and forth between the two sides but they don't want the end user to be able to see the nav links at the top. The only way I can figure out to do this is with some sort of view setting based on the permissions group but I still just can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: Site Settings -> Navigation -> edit the link and apply audience targetting to the desired SP group(s)?

Answer (score 3):

> A navigation link on a SharePoint server can be targeted so that it
>   appears only to people who are members of a particular group or
>   audience. You need to have at least Design permission in order to
>   modify the site navigation settings.

[image]

[Target a navigation link to an audience](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293)

Comment: It's worth to note that this is supported only in structural navigation and requires activation of Publishing features.